# Explicit interface implementation examples in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

A class can be derived from one or more interfaces.

If more than one interface has a method with the same signature, then the class has to implement such members of the interface explicitly.

So far in my experience I never encountered a situation where in which I had to derive from interfaces which have a method with the same signature.

Is there any examples of explicit interface implementation in .NET framework or in any publicly available libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dictionary<Key, Value>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) explicitly implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<Key,Value>>`. It is also common for classes which implement generic interfaces such as `IEnumerable<T>` to explicitly implement the non-generic counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common case is `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Both declares the method `GetEnumerator()`.

This is why when implementing `IEnumerable<T>` you have always 2 `GetEnumerator()` method to implement (`IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()  // From IEnumerable<T> interface
{
    // Code
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()  // From IEnumerable interface
{
    // Code
}
```